# Specifying dimensions of text

Tags: margins, geometry

For a submission requirement I need that my document exactly fills a box of m x n inches.

Does anybody know how I can specify this in LaTeX?

Comment: Are there any package restrictions you must adhere to? For example, [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is the go-to layout package.

Comment: \usepackage[text={m in,n in},centering]{geometry} worked well, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your document preamble, use

```
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,width=<m>in,height=<n>in]{geometry}
```

where you specify `<m>` and `<n>` (or use `text={<m>in,<n>in}`). Add the `showframe` option to see the boundaries.